# Zipline v0.8.3 how to extract Transaction Details and Daily Positions & Gains data tables

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, zipline

Running the examples file as

```
run_algo.py -c dual_moving_average.conf -o dual_moving_average.pickle
```

From that pickle how to i print the Transaction Details and Daily Positions & Gains data tables as shown on Quantopian's web site after a Full Backtest run ??

I'm looking for a python not ipython solution (i don't need the plots at this stage) and to format data as json if possible.

So far i tried something like

```
import cPickle as pickle
import pyfolio as pf

with open('./dual_moving_average.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    perf_manual = pickle.load(handle)

returns, positions, transactions, gross_lev =  pf.utils.extract_rets_pos_txn_from_zipline(perf_manual)
pf.create_full_tear_sheet(returns, positions=positions, transactions=transactions,
                      gross_lev=gross_lev)
```

it works but i don't know how to extract the tables from there

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @jezrael: For someone to reproduce the situation, first must have zipline and pyfolio installed. Then from zipline's examples folder you run

Comment: `run_algo.py -c dual_moving_average.conf -o dual_moving_average.pickle` then open a python console and enter the above mentioned commands. Also you have to be member of Quantopian's community to know how they present the information am looking for at their site.

Comment: you can use "[zipline.finance.ledger.Ledger.transactions](http://www.zipline.io/appendix.html?highlight=transaction#zipline.finance.ledger.Ledger.transactions)"